# Babel to File is working. Babel via Webpack to File is broken

Tags: webpack, babeljs

From the following source file:

```
import React from 'react';

export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Foo</div>
    );
  }
});
```

When I use babel directly, I am able to produce the following file:

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
var React = require('react');

exports.default = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'progress-label',
  render: function render() {
    return React.createElement(
      'div',
      null,
      'Foo'
    );
  }
});
```

I want to use webpack to generate this file, here is my config:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './lib/progress-label.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/example',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel'
      },
    ]
  },
  externals: {
    'react': 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
  },
};
```

When I use webpack, it results in the following file:

```
(function(e, a) { for(var i in a) e[i] = a[i]; }(exports, /******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};

/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {

/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId])
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;

/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            exports: {},
/******/            id: moduleId,
/******/            loaded: false
/******/        };

/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);

/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.loaded = true;

/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }


/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;

/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;

/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";

/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    'use strict';

    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
      value: true
    });

    var _react = __webpack_require__(1);

    var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);

    function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

    exports.default = _react2.default.createClass({
      displayName: 'progress-label',
      render: function render() {
        return _react2.default.createElement(
          'div',
          null,
          'Foo'
        );
      }
    }); // export default {
    //   foo: true,
    // };

/***/ },
/* 1 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    module.exports = require("React");

/***/ }
/******/ ])));
```

I don’t mind the webpack logic, but it won’t work as a drop-in JSX component as the first example. It results in the following errors and warnings:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `component`.

Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `component`.

./~/react/react.js
There is another module with an equal name when case is ignored.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Rename module if multiple modules are expected or use equal casing if one module is expected.

...
```

I simply want to create the same file thru webpack.

---

I believe the issue lies with this `exports.default = React.createClass({ ...` turning into this `module.exports = require("React");`

---

Versions:

- "react": "^15.4.1",
- "react-dom": "^15.4.1"
- "babel-core": "^6.20.0",
- "babel-loader": "^6.2.9",
- "webpack": "^1.12.6"

Comment: Please change the title of this question. As it stands, this isn't a good title fit for any StackExchange site unless your question directly involves errors resulting from emoji usage.

Comment: This error occurs when compiling with webpack? Or in the browser after `ReactDOM.render` ? Is there any reason you're using externals (are you loading React from another place in your html)?

Comment: FWIW I loved the old title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was multiple issues, but the way to bring in a JSX module as intended is by setting the webpack `libraryTarget` to `commonjs2`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're consistently doing:

```
import React from 'react';
```

...or

```
require('react');
```

...throughout your code-base. Module names are case-sensitive, but your file system may not be (especially on Mac or Windows). When webpack analyzes your code, mismatching cases can cause modules to resolve to the wrong thing. Do **not** do:

```
import React from 'React';
```

...or

```
require('React');
```

Also, make sure you haven't messed with `node_modules` and changed any file name casing there; if you're just doing regular `npm install` operations, you should be fine there.

Comment: Hmm .. do you see any edits above? I’m not having any problem building it, the only problem is with integration into the other codebase. The entire source code is in the first statement.

Comment: Maybe that other code base has the bad import/requires. I'd do a global search through your `node_modules` to find potential problems there.

Comment: The reason this all looks suspect is that `module.exports = require("React");` is present in your webpack file. If the `externals` was working properly, it should contain `module.exports = React`, without the `require`.

Comment: The issue I’m trying to solve is really

> I believe the issue lies with this `exports.default = React.createClass({ ...` turning into this `module.exports = require("React");`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that... the `React.createClass` is in module `0`, and the module `1` is what `react` is resolving to.

Comment: Not sure about that. I purposefully don’t have the node modules installed when generating this webpack, because it shouldn’t be using it. In the end it should be `exports.default = React.createClass({ ...`, I don’t need it to export React, the accepting environment already has React.

Comment: I will try it with node modules installed and see if that helps

Comment: It resulted in the same output

Comment: Which version of webpack are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133042/discussion-between-jacob-and-kirk-strobeck).

Answer (score 0):

The `externals` config is a little weird in that its behavior is affected by your `output.libraryTarget` being `commonjs`. With that setting, your external definition of:

```
{ react: 'React', ... }
```

...will translate the module into `module.exports = require('React')`. Note that this is also why the case-sensitive warning comes up (that warning could also mean you have required the module with different cases, but that's not the case in this instance).

If you had not set `libraryTarget` in this manner, the more typical behavior of `var` would have taken place. To override this, change your externals to:

```
{
  'react':     'var React',
  'react-dom': 'var ReactDOM'
}
```

Comment: Interesting finding, but unfortunately it still results in react being exported and not the component `module.exports = React;`